# How to know when a Cocoa app is about to quit?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsdocument, nsapplication

I have a NSDocument based application. I'd like to know when the application is about to quit to validate some things. I'd hoped there might be a method such as a applicationWillQuit, but looking through the docs for both NSDocument and NSApplication I can't find anything similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a notification you can use coming from your NSApplication:

```
NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
 [nc addObserver:self 
        selector:@selector(appWillTerminate:) 
            name:NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification 
          object:nil];
```

This is documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsapplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

By passing the object as `nil` your method is being called whenever an object fires the notification.

Comment: NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification
Posted by the terminate: method to indicate that the application will terminate.
Posted only if the delegate method applicationShouldTerminate: returns YES. The notification object is sharedApplication. This notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary.

Comment: Your app delegate can also determine if something should be done first in the applicationShouldTerminate delegate method.  NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification only says it's going to happen.

Comment: Yap, correct. `- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender` would be the method signature.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and link, exactly as needed.

Answer (score -1):

We have a delegate method in **AppDelegate.swift** or **AppDelegate.m** class. You can use it and add functionality to you application before closing it.

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}
```